# Run two operations with different frequency in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need a script in bash to run two applications with different frequency. I'm not that experienced with bash and need some help

I have two programs, m1 and m2, to be run at different rates over time (stress test). m1 is for example run every 10 seconds and m2 every 30 seconds. But it should be possible to change the frequency

Comment: You can use the cron to run the script every 20 and 30 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simplify a couple of other answers:

```
$ while sleep 10; do echo 1; done &
$ while sleep 30; do echo 2; done &
```

Note that if your "m1" and "m2" commands take time to execute, you won't be running them every 10/30 seconds.  The sleep is the delay between the end of one run and the start of the next.

So if you really want to *schedule* these so they run every 10 or 30 seconds, use cron.  Cron runs once per minute, so you need to have multiple cron jobs, offset with sleep:

```
* * * * * m1
* * * * * sleep 10; m1
* * * * * sleep 20; m1
* * * * * sleep 30; m1
* * * * * sleep 40; m1
* * * * * sleep 50; m1
* * * * * m2
* * * * * sleep 30; m2
```

Note that if `m1` takes more than 10 seconds to run, you'll overlap, which may cause your computer to vanish into a quantum singularity.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ while true; do sleep 10; echo 1; done &
$ while true; do sleep 30; echo 2; done &
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the sleep command in combination with a while true loop.

```
while true; do m1;sleep 10;done
while true; do m2; sleep 30;done
```

Comment: You should probably background both of these if you want the tests to run in parallel.  The sleep will ignore the time it takes to execute the actual commands, so the interval might be longer than you specified.  The only way to change the interval is to kill the running job and restart it with a different number of seconds in the `sleep` statement.